# Prove the ring $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$ has inverse and is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

How can I prove that $\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}}$ is of the form $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$ (i.e. that $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$ is a field)  for all rational $a,b,c$ and $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4} \neq 0$?

Comment: For all *real* $a$, $b$, $c$, this is just $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: oops, that was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very standard. Let $\phi(a,b,c)=a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$. Then
you have

$$
\phi(a,b,c)+\phi(a',b',c')=\phi(a+a',b+b',c+c')
$$

$$
\phi(a,b,c)\phi(a',b',c')=\phi(aa'+2bc'+2cb',ab'+ba'+2cc',ac'+bb'+ca')
$$

$$
\phi(a,b,c)^{-1}=\phi(\frac{a^2-2bc}{D},\frac{2c^2-ab}{D},\frac{a^2-2bc}{D}), \
D=a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc
$$

Note that $a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc \neq 0$ whenever one of $a,b$ or $c$ is nonzero.

Comment: How did you figure that out?

Comment: As I said, this is very standard. To find the coefficients in the inverse, you solve a $3\times 3$ system.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am very new to this. I know how to solve systems of equations but how do you get the system? I'm teaching myself field theory and I feel I lack the foundation to understand these sorts of things.

Comment: To get the system, you use the "multiplication law" (second equation in my answer). Given $a,b,c$, you are looking for $a',b',c'$ such that $aa'+2bc'+2cb'=1,ab'+ba'+2cc'=0,ac'+bb'+ca'=0$.

Comment: Since you are new to this, let me insist on a difficult part of the proof, that many people forget : do you realize why it is true that $a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc \neq 0$ whenever one of $a,b$ or $c$ is nonzero ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sqrt[3]4$ is $\sqrt[3]2^2$, so what you're looking at is the set of all polynomials in $\sqrt[3]2$ with rational coefficients, or to call it by its name, $\Bbb Q[\sqrt[3]2]$. What you want to show is a special case of a basic result in field theory that $\Bbb K[x]=\Bbb K(x)$.

The proof makes essential use of the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $\Bbb K$ and of Bézout's theorem for polynomials. In your case, you need to express $1/P(\sqrt[3]2)$ as a polynomial, with $P$ some polynomial, so let $M$ be the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]2$ over $\Bbb Q$. Now you need to combine that with Bézout's theorem to show that $P$ has an inverse, that is there exists $Q$ such that $P(X)Q(X)=1$, and finally use that to express your fraction as a polynomial.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you just said.

Comment: @ElliotG Do you know [Bézout's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity_for_polynomials) for polynomials? Most of what I said is really just jargon, but if you don't know that theorem, I don't know any way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: All I need to find is the inverse, though. Is there really no way to do it algebraically?

Comment: @ElliotG There is. Jack’s jargon translates into a 100% algebraic proof, though the details are mysterious if you don't know the theory. See my answer